# Yii2: Generating PDF from Markdown

Tags: php, yii2, pdf-generation, markdown

I'm using Markdown markup to generate reports. Now I need to generate PDF files from a Markdown `.md` file. There are images included in the Markdown file.

What I found so far is

- [Yii2 Extension kartik-v/yii2-markdown](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-markdown) converts markdown into HTML
- [Yii2 Extension yii2tech/html2pdf](https://github.com/yii2tech/html2pdf) converts HTML to PDF
- [Yii2 Extension kartik-v/yii2-mpdf](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf) converts HTML to PDF

What's the best way to produce the PDF output from my Markdown file? Can the mentioned libraries combined straight forward or is there an Yii2 extension / PHP library which does all of the job?

Comment: I think you should start with Markdown to HTML and then from HTML to PDF.

Comment: Have you some experiences with that way? How about images, utf8-characters,... ?

Comment: see this [link](https://codeengineered.com/blog/2014/convert-markdown-pdf-using-php/) , i am sure you can have a start from here

Comment: http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf

Comment: Using the extensions you have listed is likely the best option.